# SaaS- Tenant Specific Lookup Data in Shared Database

Tags: database, database-design, saas, multi-tenant

I am developing multitenant SaaS based application and going with Shared Database for storing all the tenant records with help of TenantId column.

Now the problem is i have some list of lookup records that needs to be shared for all the tenants. For example list of games.

**GamesTable**

```
Id
GameName
```

Also have another table used for storing only tenant specific records

**TenantGames**

```
Id
TenantId
GameName
```

The basic need is i want to use both table data and get the necessary details (Game_Name) while joining with another transaction table like UserGames. How can i achive this with this design? **Here Game_Name can be either referred from Games Shared table or TenantSpecificGames table**

Is there any other DB design which allows me to do mix both common master data and tenant master data with JOIN?

Basic requirement is keep common data and allow customization for the tenants if they want to add any new items.

Comment: What does the UserGames table look like? Instead of GameName in TenantGames use GameID which is the id field of GamesTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the design I would then use.

**Games**

```
Id
GameName
IsTenantSpecific
SomeGameSpecificColumn
```

**TenantGames**

```
GameId
TenantId
SomeTenantSpecificColumn
AnotherTenantSpecificColumn
```

Then you can query that table in a Join with:

```
...
FROM
    Games
    INNER JOIN UserGames ON
        UserGames.GameId = Games.Id
    LEFT JOIN TenantGames ON
        TenantGames.GameId = Games.Id
WHERE
    TenantGames.TenantId = @tenantId OR
    (
        TenantGames.TenantId IS NULL AND
        IsTenantSpecific = 0
    )
```

Game specific fields can be put in the Games table. Tenant specific fields can be added to the TenantGames table, and those fields will be NULL if it is not a tenant specific customization.

Comment: Might be faster to do a UNION of the two queries.

Answer (score 1):

We have a saas based database and we keep common data and tenant data in the same table.

## Concept

```
GamesTable

    Id NOT NULL
    TenantId NULL
    GameName NOT NULL
    Add a unique key for TenantId and GameName
```

- if TenantId is NULL you know it is common data
- if TenantId is NOT NULL you know it belongs to a specific tenant and who exactly.

> "Is there any other DB design which allows me to do mix both common
>   master data and tenant master data with JOIN?"

Yes

```
SELECT *
  FROM GamesTable where TenantId = 'your tenant id'
  UNION
SELECT *
  FROM GamesTable where TenantId IS NULL  -- common
```

Comment: What will happen if two tenant add the same game in Games table? Duplicate records :(

Comment: have you tried this?  You won't ever get two tenants mixed up with a query like this.  WHERE GameName NOT IN (SELECT *
          FROM GamesTable where TenantId = 'your tenant id')  if you want to filter master records where tenant has overridden.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of "many to many".

```
Table: Games
------------
GameID
GameName
IsMasterGame


TennantGames
------------------
GameID
TennantID

Tennants
------------
TennantID
...
```

To get the games for a given tennant, you would run a query like:

```
select *
from   Games
where isMasterGame = true
union
select * 
from Games g, 
TennantGames tg
where g.GameID = tg.GameID
and   isMasterGame = false
and   tg.TennantID = $currentTennant
```

(Apologies for archaic join syntax)

The union allows you to ask two questions: which games apply to everyone (`isMasterGame = true`), and secondly which games apply to the current tennant (`tg.TennantID = $currentTennant`). Logically, tennant games cannot also be master games.

Comment: Ok. Can we have a table Games contains all master games and TenantGames with tenant specified games and making Union of two?

Comment: But how do we refer/differentiate this in transaction detail table? For example UserPlayedGamesTable (Id, GameId references? ) . How can i do JOIN with both master and custom table to show the Game Name?

Comment: Ah. Well, you probably want to update the question to include this as a requirement...I'll post a proposed answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the tables leaving TenantId as NULL for records you wish to not be Tenant specific.

**Games**

```
Id
TenantId
GameName
```

The you can query that table in a Join with:

```
...
FROM
    Games
    INNER JOIN UserGames ON
        UserGames.GameId = Games.Id

WHERE
    Games.TenantId = @tenantId OR
    Games.TenantId IS NULL
```

This will save you the trouble of ensuring that the Id is unique between the tables, unless you are using a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER for the Id.

Comment: But what will happen only if two different tenant want same game? Example Tenant D, E only want Cricket. Do i need to add 2 Cricket rows with two different tenant Id? But here i feel like we are violating normalization policy.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the requirements.  See my other answer. :-)